# App to display high-level information about my network?

Tags: software-recommendation, lan

I would like to have a simple application to show information about the network I'm connected to. It should display which computers are connected, how much bandwidth they use and what they use it for. I can do this using nmap and wireshark, etc, but I would like something much simpler, that anyone can use with little information in advance. Does anyone know of such an app?

Answer (score 0):

If your network equipment supports [NetFlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow) or [sFlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFlow), you can setup `nfdump` with `NfSen` on Ubuntu to analyze your network's usage.

Here's an [excellent guide](http://code.google.com/p/installnfsen/wiki/InstallNetFlowWithNfSen) on setting up `NfSsen` which I found very useful.

[image: NFSen]